# Endless loop in a basic script on Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

i start coding in python 3.x, in my first script i do a loop, while the user type anything else than 'b 'or 'B' he stay in the loop but actually when I type 'b' or 'B' i stay in the loop and i dont know why.

Sorry for my english im a frogger you know x)

best regards

I try to correct this with a raw_input but it'seems raw_input() is not defined in python 3.x.

```
    ipt2 = input ('tapez b pour quitter')

    while ipt2 != 'b' or ipt2 != 'B':
        print(get_random_quote(quotes))
        ipt2 = input ('tapez b pour quitter')
        print(ipt2)
```

When i type B i stay in the loop and i think i have to get out of the loop, isn't it?

the last line is here to see what ipt2 's value is.

Comment: Everything is different from `b` **or** different from `B`. Presumably you want to loop `while ipt2 != 'b' and ipt2 != 'B'`.

Comment: Thank you i understand the logic behind that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are checking with `or` but in this scenario you need to use `and`:

```
ipt2 = input ('tapez b pour quitter')

while ipt2 != 'b' and ipt2 != 'B':
    print(get_random_quote(quotes))
    ipt2 = input ('tapez b pour quitter')
    print(ipt2)
```

The logic is as follows:

**First example**

ipt2 = A

with the line `while ipt2 != 'b' and ipt2 != 'B':` we check the following:

1) ipt2 is not 'b' (ipt2 is A so correct or `True`)

2) ipt2 is not 'B' (ipt2 is A so correct or `True`)

Both conditions are `True` so the loop continues.

**Second example**

ipt2 = B

now we check again:

1) ipt2 is not 'b' (ipt2 is B so correct or `True`)

2) ipt2 is not 'B' (ipt2 is B so incorrect or `False`)

One condition is `True` and the other is `False` so the loop continues, because we are checking that **conidition1** **OR** **conidition2** are True. If `ipt2` is `'B'` then ipt2 is NOT `'b'` and vice versa, one result will always be True and the loop will continue.

Comment: Thank you it work. but i don't understand why it's 'and' and not 'or' because if i type 'b' ipt2='b' but !='B' you know what i mean?

Comment: Thank you i understand the logic thank you very much.